# how does this FSharp dynamic operator

Tags: dynamic, f#, ado.net, sqldatareader

I found this fssnip http://www.fssnip.net/hh from  Tomas Petricek. It nicely hides away lots of non functional codes while using the ado.net SqlDataReader. Together with his another post on stored proc http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-sql.aspx/, it provides a nice way to query sql server using raw query and stored proc. This can be extremely useful to someone who wants to use raw query but is not lucky enough to use sqlclient type provider.

However, I can not figure out how does FSharp compiler/CLR work out the return type of the following function.

```
let (?) (reader:SqlDataReader) (name:string) : 'R =
  let typ = typeof<'R>
  if typ.IsGenericType && typ.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<option<_>> then
     if reader.[name] = box DBNull.Value then 
        (box null) :?> 'R
     else typ.GetMethod("Some").Invoke(null, [| reader.[name] |]) :?> 'R
  else
     reader.[name] :?> 'R
```

When I put a break point on this function while applying something like `reader?amount`,  (amount is a float type column). When i move cursor over the function signature it shows the return type `'R` is a double before single line of code of this function is executed. How does compiler/CLR actually know the amount is a numeric double? there is nothing in the function seems can help with the inference?

regards

casbby

Comment: There is a slightly longer version of this, together with some more explanation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh304373(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Tomas, Thanks for the link and post. it was a bit surprise there are not many discussion around interacting with older Sql server in a nice F# way. Your three posts are the closet thing I can get in F# to Dapper. Not everyone is lucky enough to have access to sql2012+.

Comment: @casbby, why are you mentioning SQL2012? Don't Tomas' tutorials work with earlier versions?

Comment: @Mau, Tomas's example is vanilla ado.net it works with any ado.net supported database. There is a type provider http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/ looks really nice, however it works only with sql server2012 onwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the key here is the `'R`.

This can be inferred at compile time from usage using standard type inference.

There is no need for explicit CLR support to figure out the return value (although, you will get an exception if the types don't match)

Comment: John, thank you. it suddenly came to me when i read your comments the third time. the reason compiler can work out the type is because I defined a record type `type figure {amount:double}`. And I yield a record {amount = reader?Amount}. if i do something silly like `SELECT firstName [Amount] from peopleTable`, compiler will infer it is a double and execution will fail because it really is a string. it was really me telling the compiler what type it is (without realising) rather than it figures out what it is magically.